# create "TouchableOpacity" for ReactJS without using react-native-web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I'd like to create a wrapper component that will behave like `react- native`s `<TouchableOpacity/>` without using `react-native-web`.

I'm thinking something that manages state and using inline styles that transitions from `.5` to `1` for opacity with a `setInterval` or should it be a css transition.

Is there anything already out there?

What's the best approach for this?

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve this affect with css transitions and using state to track when the user is clicking the button:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    touched: false
  }
  
  toggleTouched = () => {
    this.setState( prevState => ({
      touched: !prevState.touched
    }));
  }
  
  handleMouseUp = () => {
    // Handle smooth animation when clicking without holding
    setTimeout( () => {
      this.setState({ touched: false });
    }, 150);
  }
  
  render () {
    const { touched } = this.state;
    const className = touched ? 'btn touched' : 'btn';
    return (
        <button 
          className={className}
          onMouseDown={this.toggleTouched}
          onMouseUp={this.handleMouseUp}
        >
          Touch Here
        </button>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.btn {
  background: #ededed;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease;
}

.touched {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @ChaseDeAnda is really great. I have made my typescript component version of it

> TouchableOpacity.tsx

```js
import React from 'react'
import classNames from 'classnames'

import styles from './index.module.scss'

export default function TouchableOpacity({ className, children, ...rest }: TTouchableOpacityProps) {
  const [touched, touchedSet] = React.useState(false)

  return (
    <button
      className={classNames(styles.container, className)}
      style={{ opacity: touched ? 0.5 : 1, transition: 'opacity 300ms ease' }}
      onMouseDown={() => touchedSet(true)}
      onMouseUp={() => touchedSet(false)}
      {...rest}>
      {children}
    </button>
  )
}
```

> types.d.ts

```
type TTouchableOpacityProps = React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>
```

(you don't have to use the 'classnames` package - string interpolation is just fine)